# django-dynamic-formset with unique ID for each form added

Tags: jquery, django

I am using django-dynamic-formset to create inline forms (samforms) within a form(expform).(reference: http://kevindias.com/writing/django-class-based-views-multiple-inline-formsets/) Everything works fine except when I want to create an unique ID for each form added. Say, when click "add another", we can have an ID "Sample-1, Sample-2,etc". I tried the for loop counter in template but it does not work. Here is the code:

In template:

```html
<form>
    <div class="section"><span>1</span>META Data</div>
    <div class="inner-wrap">
        {{ expform.as_p }}
    </div>

    <div class="section"><span>2</span>Samples</div>
    <div class="inner-wrap">
        {{ samforms.management_form }}
        {{ samforms.non_form_errors }}
        {% for form in samforms %}
            <div class="inline {{ samforms.prefix }}">
                <label> Sample </label>
                {{ form.as_p }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="button-section" align="center">
 <input type="submit" name='create_exp' value="Create Experiment" class="submit" />
</div>
</form>
}
```

I want to have a unique ID for each form in samforms